# WP custom post type UI

Tags: php, wordpress

I use WP plugin "Custom Post Type UI" and a template of my own to add some content to my wp page.

```
<div id="AboutMain">
<?php 
    /* the original page contents */
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('content', 'page');

    /* New set of data fetched from my custom post types */
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'styrelse'
    ));

    if($posts)
    {
        foreach($posts as $post)
        {

            $namn=get_the_title($post->ID);
            $desc=get_the_content($post->ID);

            echo "
            <div class='styrelsen art-postcontent'>
                <h5 class='art-postcontent'>$namn</h5>
                <p>$desc</p>
            </div>
            ";  
        }
    }
```

Now I get a really strange behavior - since I have set the $posts with a custom query, in the for-each loop it should not contain the basic page contents anymore but my custom post type content right?

But the get_the_content($post->ID); fetches me the original contents of the page, and repeats it over and over while the get_the_title($post->ID); retrievs for me the correct title.

************ *solved* *******************'

OK, here's how I did it.

first I realized that using that global variable name might not be the best idéa so I changed it to $board_posts.

Then I dumped that variable to find out how to access the title and body 'manually' and it turns out it was easier than I first thought.

```
foreach($styrelse_posts as $post)
{   
$namn = $post->post_title;
$desc = $post->post_content;
```

trial and error beats most issues =)

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$post` as a variable can cause some weird behavior because of how Wordpress uses that as a global variable.  I'd suggest trying either calling `setup_postdata($post)` before `get_the_title($post->ID)`, or maybe changing the foreach to `foreach($posts as $p)` and using `$p->ID` as the argument.